# DataStax commnity AMI installation doesn't join other nodes

Tags: cassandra, amazon-ami

I kicked off a 6 node cluster as per the documentation on http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html. All worked ok. It's meant to be a 6 node cluster - I can see the 6 nodes working on EC dashborad. I can see OpsWork working on node 0. But the nodes are not seeing each other... I dont have access to OpsWork via browser but I can ssh to each node and verify cassandra is working.

What do I need to do so that they join the cluster. Note they all in the same VPC, same subnet in the same IP range with the same cluster name. All launched using the AMI specified in the document.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your listen address is configured. Add the "auto_bootstrap": false attribute to each node, and restart each node. Check the logs too. That would be of great help.

In my situation, turning on broadcast address to public-ip caused a similar issue. Make the broadcast address your private-ip, or just leave it untouched. If broadcasts address is a must have, have your architect modify the firewall rules.